# Emscripten PTHREAD_POOL_SIZE limitations

Tags: multithreading, webassembly, web-worker, emscripten

According to the documentation, in order to avoid deadlocks one can precreate the threadpool specifying PTHREAD_POOL_SIZE and so have a possibility of creation corresponding number of threads. But what is the influence of this parameter value on the overall performance? Does it take significant amount of time to load all the workers? Do they consume a lot of memory?